# Need to list data from a zip archive using unzip

Tags: list, solaris, unzip

Listing the contents of the zip file as below:

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ unzip -l -q /tmp/package-391.zip | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '3,$p' | grep -v '^$'

myapp/src/stage/bras.war

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

From the above I wish to create a delete file list by getting all filename that have `deployfile` and not having `DEV` which I'm able to do using the below.

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ unzip -l -q /tmp/package-391.zip | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed -n '3,$p' | grep -v '^$' | grep deployfiles | grep -v -i DEV

myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

from whatever is left i.e

```
myapp/src/stage/bras.war

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

From the leftover output, I wish to get any filenames that appear more than once i.e

```
myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
```

and add it to the delete file list

Final desired output:

```
myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
```

I will use the final desired out list to delete those files from the zip and reconstruct the zip with the below 2 files only

```
myapp/src/stage/bras.war

myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

Kindly suggest.

```
wladmin@solarishost:/tmp$ uname -a

SunOS solarishost 5.11 11.4.62.151.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on Linux

```
$ zip -d package-391.zip $(
   awk -F/ '
         (!/\/$/ && /deployfile/ && !/[dD][eE][vV]/) || (!/\/$/ && seen[$NF]++){ 
              printf "%s ", $0 
         }
   ' <(unzip -Z1 package-391.zip)
)
deleting: myapp-configuration/src/config/dev/bras.war
deleting: myapp-configuration/src/config/perf/deployfiles/acid.properties
deleting: myapp-configuration/src/config/prod/deployfiles/acid.properties
deleting: myapp-configuration/src/config/qa/deployfiles/acid.properties
deleting: myapp-configuration/src/config/uat/deployfiles/acid.properties
```

Update:
successfully testest on Solaris

```
SunOS fakename 5.11 11.4.63.157.1 i86pc i386 i86pc non-global-zone
```